# Typescript Interface Inheritance and Generics Type Infer

Tags: typescript, oop, interface, typescript-generics

I have a small issue with TypeScript interfaces, generics, classess... not sure which one of them , or my head is overwhelmed from thinking and I can't see the simple solution.
Here is my question :
Suppose I have the following interfaces :

```
interface Animal {
legs: number;
}
interface Cat extends Animal { 
meouw : string;
}
interface Dog extends Animal { 
waf : stringl 
}
```

I want to be able to do something like this :

```
interface GenericAnimal  { specimen : <T extends Animal> } ;
let someAnimals : GenericAnimal[] = [
{ specimen : {legs : 3, meouw : 'mrrrr'} } , 
{ specimen : {legs : 1, waf : 'hrrr' }
];
```

so that GenericAnimal interface can have only 'specimen'-s that are extending the Animal interface, but when initializing an GenericAnimal instance i will be able to access the extending interfaces' properties via Intellisense.
Note that using `GenericAnimal<T>` isn't my solution , due to the fact my someAnimals array would need to hold different 'animals' ( let's say I have more than 100 ) .... Using an union type might also not be a good solution. What would you suggest ?
Also is there any way I can infer the type of every item of the array after destructing it ( or iterating through the array members ) ?Ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use a [discriminating union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions), you can use [typeguards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards):

```
interface Animal {
    legs: number;
}
function isAnimal(potentialAnimal: any): potentialAnimal is Animal {
    return typeof potentialAnimal === "object" && "legs" in potentialAnimal && typeof potentialAnimal.legs === "number";
}

interface Cat extends Animal {
    meouw: string;
}
function isCat(potentialCat: any): potentialCat is Cat {
    return isAnimal(potentialCat) && "meouw" in potentialCat && typeof (potentialCat as Cat).meouw === "string"
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
    waf: string;
}
function isDog(potentialDog: any): potentialDog is Dog {
    return isAnimal(potentialDog) && "waf" in potentialDog && typeof (potentialDog as Dog).waf === "string"
}



interface GenericAnimal<T extends Animal = Animal> {
    specimen: T
              & Record<string, any> // Needed to stop extraneous prop check
};
let someAnimals: GenericAnimal[] = [
    {
        specimen: {
            legs: 3,
            meouw: 'mrrrr'
        }
    },
    {
        specimen: {
            legs: 1,
            waf: 'hrrr'
        }
    }
];

someAnimals.map((genericAnimal: GenericAnimal): Animal => {
    return genericAnimal.specimen;
}).forEach(animal =>{
    if(isCat(animal)){
        console.log(animal.meouw);
    } else if(isDog(animal)) {
        console.log(animal.waf);
    }
});


if(isCat(someAnimals[0].specimen)) {
    console.log(someAnimals[0].specimen.meouw);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkcIBzAZwC5kQBXTAI2gG5CBfQmBkBMMAD2IZMCrosuABQAHIZHDBck7DjpwQATwCUdeYsEqMasVTQncBYqSgQwDKKLBbZEITGQGIS41LwAvEHIAERCzABWEAIhyABkcaHk1LGgXgo+RjiqVgnILm4e6YbK2ZY4AHTJ5kEBoYws0CEc3ISgkLCIKADCcGDIEAAeigAm5jl4RKTImO4MAO50VGBQoBQtPHwCwqLivWByGb44+xraesWZpftmyDdTtvaOuxLlhyW4+zrxiSGzQgtUqJvMcbnkCu5PO8rp8+sg4OYvhV-gtkLVQstViAKCEuIQ2uBoPAkMgACJCCgDYY+MYWfzWabzOAwJYrNYbXj8QQiMzkijQ458s66fRHLJ824Sh4kOwOJxmCYC8UU755EJMmBAy6Cik-fKuSHIJWlCUIskqioatHBEKYta41r49pErrIADiPmgwAQEwAPAAVKmjcblNF0tQAPgIyCobgQWB8dEDiQAStEhFARr67diADTw7RRzgccj9KhCWYTWjuz2rH3lADaAF0ww2bCRpdMY3GEyA6J2u6RqnQAMy59uD0goxbIADkmCgi6gs4n024a-H0wHpFj0V7-dXk+HyAAjJvJ4zmXRZwALJcri-r0jcJscQjlyvlKjIuCyaTSCha29CY6A9EAvXrfwLgmNEo07WVnmQQDwLrCYKl3eNZhAFodAqGAMwAUUQG9pE0ekAgjTtgBgaQ9j6Ujyh0HRtxIBARHLcgqgpBj-GROZ5h0Dg1wGHAqBQajaKoPkeLUJiGUnNiQA4iAuP5Mi1EtZlBInbhOG0p0aLog4PwgKsGwABibdCeywpjO0U5TVOkEyzMs6y9ywviAQElogA)